# How to make a Linux program available on all desktops

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, gnome, virtual-desktop

In Ubuntu 10.04 running Gnome I can right click on any window and it gives me an option to show that window on all desktops, so even if I switch to a different virtual desktop, that window will always show. Is there a command in terminal that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`wmctrl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) with `-b add,sticky` attribute.
For example, to pin Firefox, do:

```
$ wmctrl -r firefox -b add,sticky
```

By default `wmctrl` treats passed strings as a substrings for case-insensitive match with target window captions; pass `-F` to let it do case-sensitive, exact comparsion, and use special values `:ACTIVE:` and `:SELECT:` to use active window or let user click on the target.

`wmctrl` may be installed with `sudo aptitude install wmctrl`.